# Google Drive, child folder into multiple parent folders

Tags: google, google-drive

I need to put a child folder in multiple parent folders. I used to be able to do it in Google Docs, but for some reason now, holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and moving or just moving, it removes it from one and adds it to another. I can't seem to make multiples.

Comment: Google Docs used to treat "folders" like labels in Gmail in that you could apply multiple labels to a document. Now that it is Drive, however, it needs to act more like the directory structure on your hard drive where, for most people, a folder only "lives" in one other folder.

Answer (score 3):

- Select the folder that you want to copy to multiple folders (this can be done by clicking the check box beside the folder)
- Click on **organize** (located on the top in between the Share button and Trash button)
- Select multiple folders (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click) in which you want to keep the child folder and then click on Apply changes

Comment: I'm surprised this actually works. It even makes copies of files in the OS file folder(s) that Drive syncs to. There's a delay, though,  so things can sometimes seem out of whack.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it this way:

Search for the file, open details from the more button and click on the folder in which the file is located :)

Comment: How does this answer the question?